# 2 Distributions Questions

Tags: combinatorics

How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfy
$a+b+c+d=18,$
where $a,b,c,d$ are positive integers?

---

How many ordered quadruples $(a,b,c,d)$ satisfy
$$a+b+c+d=18,$$
where $a,b,c,d$ are nonnegative integers?

For the first one I thought it was 18C3=816 and the second one I believe is 22C3.
Is that right?

Comment: I think it's $_{17}C_3$ and $_{21}C_3$, isn't it?  You're taking $14$ (to pre-assign one to each of $a, b, c, d$) and $18$ respectively, and adding $3$ bars.  For instance, one can add four positive integers to $6$ in $_5C_3 = 10$ different ways: $4$ permutations of $3+1+1+1$ and $6$ permutations of $2+2+1+1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place three bars between $18$ stars ([see here for the concept](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)), that is in $17$ gaps. There are
$\binom{17}3$ ways to do this.

The trick with the non-negative case is to equivalently count the number of positive quadruples summing to $18+4 = 22$ (add one to each quadruple of nonnegatives summing to $18$ and get a positive one summing to $22$ and subtract $1$ to go back). Thus we get $\binom{21}3$ ways to do that.

Comment: The nonnegative case is slightly messier because you can force the first one, two, or three numbers to be 0. But then these can be separately counted by the same technique, and then added up (using inclusion-exclusion to avoid double counting).

Comment: @Ian Not really, I added this case to show how do deal with it nicely.

Comment: That's pretty cute, +1.